# How to return results from a database in a PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

So I have this code:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $item) {
    $ref = $_SESSION['basket'][$counter];

    $result = pg_query ($conn, 'SELECT * from music WHERE ref='.$ref.' ORDER BY artist');
}
```

This will output the first row fine, however it outputs this `Warning: pg_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` if I try to retrieve more than one row. I don't understand how I'm giving a boolean to parameter 1, this is the code on line 46 where it is getting the error: 
`($row = pg_fetch_row($result))`

Thanks in advance

Comment: So where exact code which uses `pg_fetch_row`?

Comment: @u_mulder the line that uses that code is the opening of a while statement `while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {`

Comment: Okay, the query fails after the first run through the foreach loop, do I need to reset the query or result at the end of the loop so that new data can be retrieved from the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$row =pg_fetch_array($result)` and then `$row['field_name']` to take values out in the foreach loop.

The error may be because your connection variable `$conn` does not connect to your database.

Try all possibilities. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your query fails, [`pg_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php) returns `FALSE`. Also, you should use [`pg_query_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) instead to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the examples in the PHP doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php.

REMEMBER TO:

- A: Escape input, or even better use prepared statements
- B: Check the return value before iterating over the results. If an error occured it doesn't make sense to try and iterate.

In general the PHP docs are a great place, when strugling with the details of the PHP-api's, which are sometimes... Less intuitive than they could be. :-)